# Find repeated user ID in future timeframe (in R)

Tags: r

I have a table for user IDs and account logins that runs from 2017-01-01 to 2018-05-01. It's infrequent, so I want to see if they log in +/- 45 days of the same date each year (in code below I used 320/410, I'll finesse the dates later unless it's necessary for this operation).

```
loginID     userID     date
1           a          2017-01-03
2           b          2017-01-12
3           c          2017-01-14
4           d          2017-01-19
5           d          2017-10-18
6           a          2017-11-30
7           b          2017-12-09
8           c          2017-12-17
9           a          2017-12-30
10          b          2018-01-15
```

I'm trying to write a loop where the table references itself. The best I have (not working but have gone through several attempts) is:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)){
    target <- subset(df, date < (row$date+410))
    target <- subset(target, date > (row$date+320))
    target <- target$userID
    df$ninety <- row$userID %in% target
}
```

The the results I'm looking for are:

```
loginID     userID     date         repeat_oneyr
1           a          2017-01-03   TRUE
2           b          2017-01-12   TRUE
3           c          2017-01-14   TRUE
4           d          2017-01-19   FALSE
5           d          2017-10-18   FALSE
6           a          2017-11-30   FALSE
7           b          2017-12-09   FALSE
8           c          2017-12-17   FALSE
9           a          2017-12-30   FALSE
10          b          2018-01-15   FALSE
```

(Reason everything after/including 2017-10-18 is FALSE is because we don't have the login data to show whether or not they logged in between 320 and 410 days from then).

I know (from other SO questions/answers) that if I can get a TRUE/FALSE iterated over every loginID, I can use `match()` to join the data frames, so I'm not worried about that part - it's getting the TRUE/FALSE in the first place.

Any advice welcome/appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(userID) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         l45 = lead(between(c(0, diff.Date(date)), 320, 410), default = FALSE))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   userID [4]
   loginID userID date       l45  
     <int> <fct>  <date>     <lgl>
 1       1 a      2017-01-03 TRUE 
 2       2 b      2017-01-12 TRUE 
 3       3 c      2017-01-14 TRUE 
 4       4 d      2017-01-19 FALSE
 5       5 d      2017-10-18 FALSE
 6       6 a      2017-11-30 FALSE
 7       7 b      2017-12-09 FALSE
 8       8 c      2017-12-17 FALSE
 9       9 a      2017-12-30 FALSE
10      10 b      2018-01-15 FALSE
```

Comment: My internet isn't great where I am right now, sorry for the late reply.

This worked very well! Just a function of me not knowing dplyr well enough (I didn't know about the `lead` function). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could do with `data.table`. First, I order the `data.table` by userID. Second, I transform the date column to a date object. Third, I create a fwd_date column using `shift(, type="lead")`. Finally, I use an `ifelse` to create the repeat_oneyr column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setorder(df,userID)
df[,date:=as.Date(df$date)]
df[,fwd_date:=shift(date,type="lead"),by=userID]
df[,repeat_oneyr:=ifelse( (fwd_date-date < 410 & fwd_date-date > 320) 
                           & !is.na(fwd_date) ,TRUE, FALSE)]

    loginID userID       date   fwd_date repeat_oneyr
 1:       1      a 2017-01-03 2017-11-30         TRUE
 2:       6      a 2017-11-30 2017-12-30        FALSE
 3:       9      a 2017-12-30       <NA>        FALSE
 4:       2      b 2017-01-12 2017-12-09         TRUE
 5:       7      b 2017-12-09 2018-01-15        FALSE
 6:      10      b 2018-01-15       <NA>        FALSE
 7:       3      c 2017-01-14 2017-12-17         TRUE
 8:       8      c 2017-12-17       <NA>        FALSE
 9:       4      d 2017-01-19 2017-10-18        FALSE
10:       5      d 2017-10-18       <NA>        FALSE
```

**DATA**

```
df<-read.table(text="loginID     userID     date
1           a          2017-01-03
2           b          2017-01-12
3           c          2017-01-14
4           d          2017-01-19
5           d          2017-10-18
6           a          2017-11-30
7           b          2017-12-09
8           c          2017-12-17
9           a          2017-12-30
10          b          2018-01-15",header=T)
```